# Tabbing to off canvas elements

Tags: css, html

I'm creating a slide in menu -w hen not on display the panel is hidden off canvas. However, I've noticed that when using the TAB key, elements not visible at the time get focus bringing the off-canvas panel into view.

Any ideas as to how to deal with this?

Comment: Can you provide your code to try finding a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using html5 you can add `tabindex='-1'` to disable getting focus by tabs.

Of course if necessary you can always re-enable them when the panel is viewable.